# How should I configure grid

Tags: html, css

I have created a landscape prototype and now I have to code it in HTML5&CSS.

For the layout part I have decided to use grid and as you see below, that's how I structured it on paper before coding. Now because I want to make the landscape responsive I am not sure if the parameters given to the grid template are correct.

**Prototype**

[image]

**Sketch**

[image]

**HTML**

```
   <div class="landscape-grid">
        <div class="landscape-grid__left-bar"></div>
        <div class="landscape-grid__header"></div>
        <div class="landscape-grid__main-content"></div>
        <div class="landscape-grid__video"></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.landscape-grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3.28125% 53.489583333333% 43.2291666666667%;
    grid-template-rows: 75px 168px 711px auto; 
}
```

As you can see I tried to keep the columns proportional and translated the pixels into proportions. 
However, I m not sure this method is the best fit for this example, because I see a lot of people using fr's and min-content/max-content attributes on their grids. How should that apply to mine?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask yourself a couple of things to make this kind of decision:

1. What does the mobile/tablet/responsive view look like? It might be that flex is more suitable depending on how you want it to look.
2. What elements have fixed sizes. For example the image on the right. Is this a fixed width/height? If not then you can think about using fr with object-fit for appropriate scaling. If it is fixed then everything else will depend on the size of that.

If you're widths are relative then generally using fractional units is better than percentages but you need to take into consideration how the image scales.

Here is a good guide to grid, you should look here to see all the best ways of using it: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/.

The first thing I'd recommend you do is a mobile and tablet prototype though. It's not easy to ask how to make something responsive when we don't know what the mobile view looks like!